# Two- or three-authored papers key

Tags: bibtex

I would like to cite a paper from 2010 with two or there authors (say, Miller, Javier and Smith) such that the key in the text appears as `[MilJavSmi10]`. Similar to what is done for a single-authored paper. Currently, with the `alpha` mode, it appears as `[MJS10]`. For more than three authors, I prefer the key to stick to the default `alpha` mode.

Is it possible to achieve this with `bibtex` (without using `biber`)?